# Count the amount of numbers that are length of 5 and has exactly two repeating numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the amount of numbers that are length of 5 and has exactly two repeating numbers (where zero can be leading like `00123`). What I did:

```
def checkNumber(num):
    temp = [0] * 10
    for d in map(int, str(num)):
        temp[d] += 1
    contains_two_unique_digits = False
    for d in temp:
        if d > 2:
            return False
        if d == 2:
            if contains_two_unique_digits:
                return False
            contains_two_unique_digits = True
    return True

counter = 0
for num in range(10000,100000):
    counter += checkNumber(num)
print(counter)
```

But of course it does not count the cases with a leading zeros. How can I add them here? Python does not allow `001234` numbers.

Comment: You can force the input to be a string, if that's not a problem.  That way, you can have numbers that start with 0.  If you NEED the input to be a `int`/`float` type, you may have to wait for a more helpful answer.

Comment: I agree with Lakshya, this is a string problem not an integer problem. Your function should also return False by default, not True. `checkNumber('12345') >>>True`

Comment: Additionally, your logic where `if d==2` is rather confusing. You only need to return True if d==2, everything else should return False. Meaning, you can `return d==2`.

Comment: In `00123` do you consider `00` as repeating numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The `zfill` method of the `str` type might be of help.

```
>>> "123".zfill(5)
'00123'
>>> "123456789".zfill(5)
'123456789'
```

To convert an `int` to a `str`, simply use `str`:

```
>>> str(123)
'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you NEED to accept integers in python, then you are correct that no solution can be made. If you can accept a string and treat the values inside as integers, then you can definitely make it happen. A integer or float with leading zeros will always cause an error in Python.

```
def checkNumber(string_input):
    # is it a string?
    if not isinstance(string_input, str):
        string_input = str(string_input)
    # does it have five characters?
    if not len(string_input) == 5:
        raise ValueError('You must enter a string of length 5.')

    counter_list = [0] * 10
    # iterate over the string and count how many of each integer we have
    for value in string_input:
        if value.isdigit():
            counter_list[int(value)] += 1

    # check to see if any of them have identically two
    for value_count in counter_list:
        if value_count == 2:
            return True
    return False

print(checkNumber('01234'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over numbers by their digit representation, then `itertool.product()` will likely be more useful. `itertools.product(string.digits, repeat=5)` will yield each of the numbers you need, as digit tuples.

Taking advantage of `collections.Counter` can also help here, and avoids the flag / loop logic.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product
from typing import Tuple
import string


def has_two_repeats(digits: Tuple[str, ...]):
    counts = Counter(digits).values()
    return (
        # no digits occur more than 2 times
        sum(count > 2 for count in counts) == 0 and
        # one digit occcurs two times
        sum(count == 2 for count in counts) == 1
    )


def all_two_repeats_five_digits() -> int:
    return sum(
        has_two_repeats(digits)
        for digits in product(string.digits, repeat=5)
    )


print(all_two_repeats_five_digits())
```